# more concise jquery for multi button controlling visibility of same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons that control the visibility of 1 div.

we want to do following to div:

- show the first time any of three buttons are clicked
- show if button clicked is different to previously button click
- hide if button clicked is the same as previous clicked and if div is currently visible
- show if button clicked is the same as previous clicked and if div is currently invisible

currently I have this:

```
//$('#alert_area') = target div

$button = $('.button')

if ($button.attr('id') != $('#alert_area').attr('showing')){
    $('#alert_area').show()
}else{
    if ($('#alert_area').is(":visible")){
        $('#alert_area').hide(); 
    }else{
        $('#alert_area').show(); 
    }
}
$('#alert_area').attr('showing', $button.attr('id'))
```

Comment: ... Are you requesting that someone write the rest of your code for you?

Comment: This should probably go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: codereview looks like the place for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a slight improvement, but you can replace your `else` block with `toggle`.  You can also cache your selector to neaten things up.

```
 var $button = $('.button'), $alertArea = $("#alert_area");

 if ($button.attr('id') != $alertArea.attr('showing')) {
     $alertArea.show()
 } else {
     $alertArea.toggle();
 }

 $alertArea.attr('showing', $button.attr('id'));
```